# How can I use mod_rewrite on current directory only?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have these rules in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*).css style.php?u=$1 [QSA]
        RewriteRule ^(.*).xml rss.php?u=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This will rewrite the following URLs:

```
 http://domain.com/user.css
 http://domain.com/user.xml
```

But when I'm trying to grab a file from a subdirectory: `http://domain.com/css/style.css` it gets rewritten as well.

My goal is rewrite only for current directory and avoid sub-directories, since all real CSS files on sub-directories will be rewritten.

How I can avoid this?

Comment: 1) Where this .htaccess is located -- in root folder or elsewhere? 2) As I understand these rules are to rewrite requests to .css/.xml that are located in root folder ONLY (e.g. `http://domain.com/user.css`), and you do not want these rules to rewrite requests to .css files in subfolders (e.g. `http://domain.com/css/style.css`)?

Comment: 1- Yes, the htaccess file is locate at the same dir of style.php and rss.php.<br>2- yes, i just want to rewrite rules for current dir, but when load http://domain.com/css-or-some-dir/somefile.css, somefile is calling the style.php located at root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your pattern more restrictive: this `^(.*).css` will match ANYTHING with `.css` in it while this pattern `^([^/]+)\.css$` will be restricted to `something.css` (`styles\something.css` will not match it).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # do not do anything to real files or folders
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule .+ - [L]

        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.css$ style.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.xml$ rss.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for above answer, I have one more question: I have a real css file locate at same directory, and is re-writed too, how i can avoid, if filename is style.css?

Comment: Check my updated answer. That is one way. Another -- add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/style.css` **or** `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line before `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.css$ style.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]`. It really depends on situation which one is better. If you have quite a few rewrite rules, then the one in answer may be better.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to tell mod_rewrite to avoid rewriting if the file is a real file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*).css           style.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*).xml           rss.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've added a `[L]` tag (end) because once a rule is applied you certainly doesn't need the next rule to be checked.

Now if the files really exists but you really want to handle them with a php script if no 'css' subdirectory is present on the url... let's try that:

```
<Location "/css">
    RewriteEngine off
</Location>
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstand me, i want to rewrite these files only for current directory and avoid all sub-directories.